# Use VLOOKUP as criteria inside COUNTIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2016

After years of using this community, I have a question that I can't find an answer to. I hope you all can help!

I am trying to get a count of the number of "Grounded" items that each individual is overdue for. My screenshot ([Count Tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ4AV.png)) shows a very condensed version of what I'm working with. Columns A-C is my large (15,000 rows) data field that is imported from an external source. In columns G-H I have listed each possible task (about 100 rows) and the type (Grounded and Non-Grounding plus many others). Column F is where I am trying to get the count.

My formula in F9 currently uses COUNTIFS to get a count of the instances in the large array that equal E9 ("Smith" in this case) and where the due date in the large array is less than or equal to the current date in F8. What I can't figure out is how to also add to count the Tasks in the large array where the task type in Column H equals "Grounded". I tried VLOOKUP, but it seems it doesn't like it and tells me there is a problem with the formula. It doesn't work, but here's the general idea of what I'm after:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$E9,$C$2:$C$7,"<="&$F$8,VLOOKUP($B$2:$B$7,$G$2:$H$4,2,FALSE),"=Grounded")
```

With how the data is currently presented, Smith should have a count of 1 and Jones should have a count of 0. I have a feeling that this is more simple than I'm making it to be, but I can't figure it out. I am using Excel 2016.

Hopefully I explained the problem well enough. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Excel 2016 I'd say `MMULT()` is a good alternative here:

[image]

CSE-Formula in `F9`:

```
=SUM((A$2:A$7=E9)*(MMULT((TRANSPOSE(G$2:G$4)=B$2:B$7)*(TRANSPOSE(H$2:H$4)="Grounding"),ROW(G$2:G$4)^0))*(C$2:C$7<=F$8))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. From your screenshot it looks like it evaluates correctly on your end, but when I try to do it I don't get the correct values. Just entering either formula as you have it results in #VALUE!. If I enter either formula using CSE, Smith evaluates to 2 and Jones to 1. It is only looking at the first value in column B, not any of the others. If I change the CRM type to Non-Grounding then Smith and Jones evaluate to 0. Am I entering it in wrong?

Comment: @Palidor, you are absolutely correct. The above won't work in Excel 2016 as I have tested in ms365 assuming it would work. However then dynamic arrays which worked for me in the match or vlookup won't work in 2016

Comment: Edited the answer to accomodate for that. @Palidor

Comment: that works beautifully. I'll have to take a deep look at why it works as it's not something I would have ever thought of doing. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a fourth column that stores whether that Task is Grounded

The formula for D2 would then be:

```
=INDEX($H$2:$H$4,MATCH(B2,$G$2:$G$4,0))
```

Modify your CountIfs formula to use this new column as a criteria

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$E9,$C$2:$C$7,"<="&$F$8,$D$2:$D$7, "Grounded")
```

Comment: That's similar to how I'm doing it right now. I was hoping there would be a way to do it without adding an extra column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Sumproduct+Vlookup formula without helper solution, and can work for your Excel 2016

In `F9`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$7=E9)*(VLOOKUP(T(IF({1},$B$2:$B$7)),G$2:H$4,2,0)="Grounded")*($C$2:$C$7<=$F$8))
```

[image]